# preg_replace function kills my page

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

I've built a php page generator, inserts a bunch of data into a pre-made HTML template.

I'm using preg_replace to remove all white spacing and it seems to be killing my page.

On localhost: Page 1.html holding the form works fine, I click the generate button which goes to the next page with the HTML code with data inserted. The code isn't rendered as a page, simply displayed for copying.
But the preg_replace just causes my that one page to display: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {

$search = array(
'/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
'/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
'/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
);

$replace = array(
'>',
'<',
'\\1'
);

$buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

return $buffer;
}

ob_start("sanitize_output");
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue, do you only see the PHP code as text or do you get a 500 error?

Comment: Sorry, in Firefox, it simply shows a "The connection was reset" error message. And Chrome says ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. On Mobile Safari, it says "502 Bad Gateway". Oddly, it's now (for now?) working fine on Chrome and the page loads properly, but not on other browsers.

Comment: Put this on the first line of your page `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and tell us what you got.

Comment: Did you solve it? Note that  you should not escape `>` and `<` chars in a regex.